# Group every 6 elements in DIV with remaining last elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an array with n no of items,  I want to group every 6 of them in a seperate div's. but suppose I have 15 items in array . I am not able to group last three remaining items.

I tried the following and it groups every 6 elements well. but not last last remaining 3 items.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mockData; let i = index;">
          <div class="inner-wrap" *ngIf="(i+1) % 6 ==0">
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-5]">{{ mockData[i-5] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-4]">{{ mockData[i-4] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-3]">{{ mockData[i-3] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-2]">{{ mockData[i-2] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-1]">{{ mockData[i-1] }}</p>
            <p>{{ item  }} </p>
          </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create sub-arrays, iterate them, and then iterate each sub-array to show up as a `div` element

---

In your `.ts` file, create a function like this:

```
  createMockGroup() {
    return (mockData || [])
      .reduce((a, _, i, arr) => {
        if (i % 6 === 0)
          a.push(arr.slice(i, i + 6));
        return a;
      }, []);
  }
```

In your `.html` file, modify the content as:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of createMockGroup()">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of group">
         <p>{{ item }} </p>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

In this example you don't need to use `index` at all

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if any remainder is there after you group by 6. Here is a sample code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mockData; let i = index;">
          <div class="inner-wrap" *ngIf="(( (i+6) < mockData.length) && ((i+1) % 6 ==0)) || (i == mockData.length - (mockData.length % 6))">
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-5]">{{ mockData[i-5] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-4]">{{ mockData[i-4] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-3]">{{ mockData[i-3] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-2]">{{ mockData[i-2] }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="mockData[i-1]">{{ mockData[i-1] }}</p>
            <p>{{ item  }} </p>
          </div> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Tried your solution, It make no difference in output. Output remains same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let groupIndex of createGroup(mockData, 6);">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)] }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)+1]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)+1] }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)+2]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)+2] }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)+3]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)+3] }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)+4]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)+4] }}</p>
        <p *ngIf="mockData[(groupIndex*6)+5]">{{ mockData[(groupIndex*6)+5] }}</p>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

append this method to your component:

```
createGroup(arr, count){
    let grouplist = [];
    let maxNum = (arr.length % count) == 0 ? (arr.length / count) : (arr.length / count)+1;

    for(var i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
        grouplist.push(i);
    }
    return grouplist;
}
```

Comment: Tried this  code, same issue.  For an array of lets say 13 items , your code will fail at (arr.length%count).

Comment: Edited and tested

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mockData; let i = index;">
  <div class="inner-wrap" *ngIf="i % 6 ==0">
    <p>{{ item  }} </p>
    <p *ngIf="mockData[i+1]">{{ mockData[i+1] }}</p>
    <p *ngIf="mockData[i+2]">{{ mockData[i+2] }}</p>
    <p *ngIf="mockData[i+3]">{{ mockData[i+3] }}</p>
    <p *ngIf="mockData[i+4]">{{ mockData[i+4] }}</p>
    <p *ngIf="mockData[i+5]">{{ mockData[i+5] }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvzyvv)

Answer (score 0):

in your component

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[]): any[] {
     const R = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 6) {
      R.push(items.slice(i, i + 6));
     }
     return R
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  number = ['', ' ', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]

}
```

and in html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of number | filter ; let i = index" style="border: 1px solid;margin-bottom:20px">
<div *ngFor="let item of item; let j = index" style="">
  element {{i}} , {{j}}
</div>
</div>
```

stackblitz-https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppnxnm